# Write a function named countCharacter(filename) that accepts a text file’s name and returns

Tags: python

Write a function named countCharacter(filename) that accepts a text file’s name and returns

- The number of uppercase letters in the file.
- The number of lowercase letters in the file.
- The number of digits in the file.
- The number of whitespace characters in the file.
- Call your function on sonnets.txt (50 pts)

```
def countCharacter(filename):
    upper_case, lower_case, digits, space = 0, 0, 0, 0
    try:
        f = open(filename)
        for line in f:
            for ch in line:
                if ch.isupper():
                    upper_case += 1
        if ch.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        if ch.isdigit():
            digits += 1
            if ch.isspace():
                space += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    
    upper_case ,lower_case ,digits ,space = countCharacter('sonnets.txt')
    print("Upper case = ",upper_case )
    print("Lower case = ",lower_case )
    print("Digits case = ",digits )
    print("Spaces case = ",space )
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement in the method

Comment: def countCharacter(filename):
    upper_case, lower_case, digits, space = 0, 0, 0, 0
try:
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f:
        for ch in line:
            if ch.isupper():
                upper_case += 1
    if ch.islower():
        lower_case += 1
    if ch.isdigit():
        digits += 1
        if ch.isspace():
            space += 1
except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
return upper_case, lower_case, digits, space;

Comment: This looks like your homework. It says 50 pts. :)

Answer (score 0):

`countCharacter` is returning `None` make sure to return value

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

def countCharacter(filename):
    upper_cases, lower_cases, digits, spaces = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                for ch in line:
                    if ch.isupper():
                        upper_cases += 1
                    if ch.islower():
                        lower_cases += 1
                    if ch.isdigit():
                        digits += 1
                    if ch.isspace():
                        spaces += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    return (upper_cases, lower_cases, digits, spaces)

upper_cases ,lower_cases ,digits , spaces = countCharacter('sonnets.txt')
print("Upper case = ",upper_cases )
print("Lower case = ",lower_cases )
print("Digits case = ",digits )
print("Spaces case = ",spaces )
```